# How to parse html documents using standard windows phone libraries?

Tags: html, windows-phone

I heard that there is one external library called "Html Agility Pack" that can solve the problem. My question is that is there any approach using only standard libraries for that purpose? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, if HtmlAgilityPack can solve your issue, use it then. Silly question!

Comment: I used XmlReader instead. Also another standard option is to use XDocument. If a standard library set cannot solve the very basic problems, that'll be called silly. Thank you anyway!